# MySQL - On delete cascade constraint doesn't do it's job properly

Tags: mysql, constraints, cascade

I have a couple of tables:

- `users` is full of users.
- `item` is full of items.
- `item` can have multiple `second_item`s.
- `users` are able to have `second_item`s via table `users_items`.

When I delete a `item` all `second_item` and `users_items` should be removed too. So I setup some constraints that should delete child table records. But it leaves the record in `users_items`.

Here is my MySQL queries:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `item` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'test');

CREATE TABLE `second_item` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `second_item` (`id`, `item_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'test');

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (1, 'test', 'test');

CREATE TABLE `users_items` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_second_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users_items` (`id`, `user_id`, `item_id`, `item_second_id`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1);

ALTER TABLE `second_item`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `item_id` (`item_id`);

ALTER TABLE `item` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `users` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `users_items`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  ADD KEY `item_second_id` (`item_second_id`);


ALTER TABLE `second_item`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `constraint1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `users_items`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `constraint2` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `constraint3` FOREIGN KEY (`item_second_id`) REFERENCES `second_item` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `constraint4` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I try to do the following delete query, but it leaves a record in `users_items`:

```
DELETE FROM `item` WHERE `item`.`id` = 1;
```

This "bug" happens on:

- WAMP (Server version: 5.7.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL))
- UBUNTU (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu))

EDITED:

The bug is caused by the order you add constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE `users_items`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `constraint1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `constraint2` FOREIGN KEY (`item_second_id`) REFERENCES `second_item` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `constraint3` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `second_item`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `constraint4` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

This way it is fixed.

Comment: Works fine in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52b604/1 ?

Comment: +1 at least for creating a minimal case to reproduce the problem! Thank you! Not many questions do that.

Comment: I also tested on my local MySQL instance. It works, after I run the delete from `item` I see the row in `users_items` has also been deleted. I suggest you re-do your test carefully. You must have made a mistake.

Comment: @BillKarwin I did this exact test in WAMP (Server version: 5.7.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)). I am left with a record in both `users` and ` users_items`. The same goes for my ubuntu server (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had indeed the same results as you had.
Also found the fix ;)

Change the order of your constraints in your SQL code. This will solve your problem.

I think this is a weird MySQL Bug